# XSLT merge nodes with the same identifier element

Tags: xml, xslt, join, merge

in the following example the requirement is to merge `<userSearchRecords>` elements (identified by `<userAccount/login>` element) by moving `<otherAttributes>` child element if needed, meaning: if there are 2 `<userSearchRecords>` elements in the xml, join them by moving the `<otherAttributes>` from the second `<userSearchRecords>` to the first one, and remove the second `<userSearchRecords>` element; otherwise leave it as it is.

Example input XML:

```
<SearchReply_OutputVariable>
  <part name="parameters">
    <searchResponse>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>A</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>X</name>
            <value>1</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>B</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>X</name>
            <value>2</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>C</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>X</name>
            <value>1</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>D</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>X</name>
            <value>1</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>G</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>Y</name>
            <value>5</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>C</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>Y</name>
            <value>6</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>H</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>Y</name>
            <value>7</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>A</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>Y</name>
            <value>7</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
    </searchResponse>
  </part>
</SearchReply_OutputVariable>
```

Expected output XML:

```
<SearchReply_OutputVariable>
  <part name="parameters">
    <searchResponse>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>A</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>X</name>
            <value>1</value>
          </otherAttributes>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>Y</name>
            <value>7</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>B</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>X</name>
            <value>2</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>C</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>X</name>
            <value>1</value>
          </otherAttributes>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>Y</name>
            <value>6</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>D</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>X</name>
            <value>1</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>G</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>Y</name>
            <value>5</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
      <userSearchRecords>
        <userAccount>
          <login>H</login>
          <otherAttributes>
            <name>Y</name>
            <value>7</value>
          </otherAttributes>
        </userAccount>
      </userSearchRecords>
    </searchResponse>
  </part>
</SearchReply_OutputVariable>
```

In the output XML there are now 6 `<userSearchRecords>`, while in the input XML there were 8. In the input XML there were 2 `<userSearchRecords>` with `<login>` value A, and 2 `<userSearchRecords>` with `<login>` value C. In the output XML these elements were merged (`<otherAttributes>` child moved from the matched login pair and `<userSearchRecords>` element from the matched pair removed).

Can someone point me in the right direction, how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a grouping problem. With XSLT 2.0 you can use `<xsl:for-each select="userSearchRecords" group-by="userAccount/login">`, with XSLT 1.0 you use Muenchian grouping with a key `<xsl:key name="group" match="userSearchRecords" use="userAccount/login"/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Martin, I looked up 'grouping' related to xsl and this is what I came up as a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="group" match="userSearchRecords" use="userAccount/login"/>

 <xsl:template match="searchResponse">
    <searchResponse>
       <xsl:for-each select="userSearchRecords[count(. | key('group', userAccount/login)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="userAccount/login" />
        <userSearchRecords>
            <userAccount>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('group', userAccount/login)">
                    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::userSearchRecords[userAccount/login = current()/userAccount/login])">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="userAccount/login"/>
                    </xsl:if>               
                    <xsl:copy-of select="userAccount/otherAttributes"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </userAccount>
        </userSearchRecords>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </searchResponse>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```